# springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, jms, transactionmanager

I am running a spring boot application that communicates with ActiveMQ and a SQL database, and I am facing the following problem: spring cannot auto configure the DB transaction manager for connecting to the database, it will always pick the wrong one (JMSTransactionManager).
I am using the JpaRepository interface to communicate with the database, i.e, I am not using entity manager to talk to the database.
How can solve this issue?

this is my configuration class

```
@EnableJms
@EnableTransactionManagement
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {
    

    
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager() {
        return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory());
    }
@Bean 
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
        JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        return manager;
    }
    
      
}
```

I am using both transaction managers on this method

```
    @Transactional(value="jpaTransactionManager")
    public Image saubmitImage(ImageDirectory dir) {
        return dao.save(new Image());
    }
```

the error I am getting when I am calling the database is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.transaction.TransactionManager' available: expected single matching bean but found 2: jmsTransactionManager,jpaTransactionManager,
```

thanks in advance guys

Comment: Are you sure this specific method is the culprit? When is the error thrown? Could you please post the entire stack trace?

Comment: I just updated the question with the entire stack trace

Comment: Why are `jpaTransactionManager()` and `chainedTransactionManager(...)` not public? Beans declared using non-public methods will not be accessible outside `JmsConfig`

Comment: thanks for the note, I changed it to public and I still have the same error. It is not the case because the Bean should be accessible through the context not by import, but thanks anyway

Comment: A moment ago, the question had `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`, now it's `NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException`, so which is it? You realize you're not exactly helping by changing the question details without notice, right? Those are two very different exceptions, with potentially different solutions

Comment: And by the way, that's exactly what I meant by beans not being accessible if they are not defined using public methods. They are not accessible *through the context* outside of the declaring `@Configuration`. That's how Spring interprets modifiers on `@Bean` declarations

Comment: thanks again, NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException this is the one I have. when I updated the question for posting the entire stack trace as you asked, I did not post the correct one that why I changed it as fast I can. sorry for the confusion. the error has always been this  NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException. thanks for helping again

Answer (score 1):

For your operations to be truly atomic you need to use a JTA transaction manager in order to coordinate the transaction phases (e.g. prepare, commit, rollback) between all the resources (i.e. JMS, database). Check out the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.x/reference/html/boot-features-jta.html) on this. [This Spring blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2011/08/15/configuring-spring-and-jta-without-full-java-ee/) might also be helpful.

Comment: thanks Justin, but prepare, commit, rollback will be out of the box, I do not want more than the default behaviour, I would do that approach if I want to customize any of the default behaviour. I'm I right?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean. If you don't use a JTA transaction manager with XA resources then your operations *won't* actually be atomic. They may be correlated, but if you have failures then your data can become inconsistent. Using JTA isn't any less "out of the box" than any other approach. The support is built into Spring Boot (as the linked documentation describes).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this question is to change the name of the method that returns the transaction manager and defined a qualifier to identify the transaction manager at run time
like so :

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("jmsTransactionManager")
public PlatformTransactionManager jmsTransactionManager() {
    return new JmsTransactionManager(connectionFactory());
}

@Bean
@Primary
@Qualifier("jpaTransactionManager")
public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager manager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    return manager;
}
```

and in the service class I have specified which transaction manager to use for the method like so :

```
@Service
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.READ_COMMITTED, value="jpaTransactionManager")
public class ImageService implements ImgService
```

so spring can pick the correct one at runtime

on the JMS class I did the same

```
@Autowired
private JmsTemplate jmsTemplate;

@Transactional("jmsTransactionManager")
public void send(Image image){
jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(IMAGE_QUEUE,image);
}
```